# mininum value of struct type column in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My question is I have below json file where it contains struct type data for column3. I can able to extract the rows but not able to find the mininum value of column3. Where column3 contain dinamic nested columns(dynamic names) with values.

inputdata is:

```
"result": { "data" : 
[ {"col1": "value1",  "col2": "value2",  "col3" : { "dyno" : 3, "aeio": 5 }, "col4": "value4"},
   {"col1": "value11", "col2": "value22", "col3" : { "abc" : 6, "def": 9 , "aero": 2}, "col4": "value44"},
   {"col1": "value12", "col2": "value23", "col3" : { "ddc" : 6}, "col4": "value43"}]
```

outputDate expecting as:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5(min value of col3)

value1  value2  [3,5]   value4  3

value11 value22 [6,9,2] value44 2

value12 value23 [6] value43 6
```

I can able to read the file and explode the data as records but not able to find the min value of col3.

```
val bestseller_df1 = bestseller_json.withColumn("extractedresult", explode(col("result.data")))
```

can you please help me to code to find the min value of col3 in spark/scala.

my json file is:

```
{"success":true, "result": { "data": [ {"col1": "value1",  "col2": "value2",  "col3" : { "dyno" : 3, "aeio": 5 }, "col4": "value4"},{"col1": "value11", "col2": "value22", "col3" : { "abc" : 6, "def": 9 , "aero": 2}, "col4": "value44"},{"col1": "value12", "col2": "value23", "col3" : { "ddc" : 6}, "col4": "value43"}],"total":3}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it

```
scala> val df = spark.read.json("/tmp/stack/pathi.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: struct<data: array<struct<col1:string,col2:string,col3:struct<abc:bigint,aeio:bigint,aero:bigint,ddc:bigint,def:bigint,dyno:bigint>,col4:string>>, total: bigint>, success: boolean]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- abc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- aeio: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- aero: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ddc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- def: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dyno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- total: long (nullable = true)
 |-- success: boolean (nullable = true)


scala> df.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|result                                                                                                                         |success|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|[[[value1, value2, [, 5,,,, 3], value4], [value11, value22, [6,, 2,, 9,], value44], [value12, value23, [,,, 6,,], value43]], 3]|true   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+

scala> df.select(explode($"result.data")).show(false)
+-----------------------------------------+
|col                                      |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[value1, value2, [, 5,,,, 3], value4]    |
|[value11, value22, [6,, 2,, 9,], value44]|
|[value12, value23, [,,, 6,,], value43]   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

By looking at the schema, now we know the list of possible columns inside "col3", so we can compute the minimum of all those values by hard-coding as below

```
scala> df.select(explode($"result.data")).select(least($"col.col3.abc",$"col.col3.aeio",$"col.col3.aero",$"col.col3.ddc",$"col.col3.def",$"col.col3.dyno")).show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|least(col.col3.abc, col.col3.aeio, col.col3.aero, col.col3.ddc, col.col3.def, col.col3.dyno)|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|3                                                                                           |
|2                                                                                           |
|6                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Dynamic handling:**

I'll assume that upto col.col3, the structure remains the same, so we proceed by creating another dataframe as

```
scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("res_data",explode($"result.data")).select(col("success"),col("res_data"),$"res_data.col3.*")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [success: boolean, res_data: struct<col1: string, col2: string ... 2 more fields> ... 6 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|success|res_data                                 |abc |aeio|aero|ddc |def |dyno|
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|true   |[value1, value2, [, 5,,,, 3], value4]    |null|5   |null|null|null|3   |
|true   |[value11, value22, [6,, 2,, 9,], value44]|6   |null|2   |null|9   |null|
|true   |[value12, value23, [,,, 6,,], value43]   |null|null|null|6   |null|null|
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Other than "success" and "res_data", the rest of the columns are the dynamic ones from "col3"

```
scala> val p = df2.columns
p: Array[String] = Array(success, res_data, abc, aeio, aero, ddc, def, dyno)
```

Filter those two and map the rest of them to spark Columns

```
scala> val m = p.filter(_!="success").filter(_!="res_data").map(col(_))
m: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(abc, aeio, aero, ddc, def, dyno)
```

Now pass `m:_*` as argument to the least function and you get your results as below

```
scala> df2.withColumn("minv",least(m:_*)).show(false)
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|success|res_data                                 |abc |aeio|aero|ddc |def |dyno|minv|
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|true   |[value1, value2, [, 5,,,, 3], value4]    |null|5   |null|null|null|3   |3   |
|true   |[value11, value22, [6,, 2,, 9,], value44]|6   |null|2   |null|9   |null|2   |
|true   |[value12, value23, [,,, 6,,], value43]   |null|null|null|6   |null|null|6   |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+


scala>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

dbutils.fs.put("/tmp/test.json", """

{"col1": "value1",  "col2": "value2",  "col3" : { "dyno" : 3, "aeio": 5 }, "col4": "value4"},

{"col1": "value11", "col2": "value22", "col3" : { "abc" : 6, "def": 9 , "aero": 2}, "col4": "value44"},

{"col1": "value12", "col2": "value23", "col3" : { "ddc" : 6}, "col4": "value43"}]}
""", true)

val df_json = spark.read.json("/tmp/test.json")

val tf = df_json.withColumn("col3", explode(array($"col3.*"))).toDF

val tmp_group = tf.groupBy("col1").agg( min(tf.col("col3")).alias("col3"))

val top_rows = tf.join(tmp_group, Seq("col3","col1"), "inner")

top_rows.select("col1", "col2", "col3","col4").show()

Wrote 282 bytes.

+-------+-------+----+-------+

|   col1|   col2|col3|   col4|

+-------+-------+----+-------+

| value1| value2|   3| value4|

|value11|value22|   2|value44|

|value12|value23|   6|value43|

+-------+-------+----+-------+